# mod_vhost_alias + suEXEC: auto selecting uid/gid

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, php5, suexec

I'm trying to configure **Debian 6.0.4** for massive shared hosting with **PHP5**.
Packages `apache2-mpm-worker libapache2-mod-fcgid apache2-suexec` are installed.

I successfully loaded `mod_vhost_alias` and `suexec` to manage my domains by directory, then I placed this configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-vhostalias`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
ServerName web-test.mynet.lan
DocumentRoot /var/www/

SuexecUserGroup www-data www-data    

UseCanonicalName    Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/www.%2+/public_html/
VirtualScriptAlias /var/www.%2+/cgi-bin/

DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.shtml index.php   

ScriptAlias /__php5-cgi/ "/usr/local/lib/custom-cgi/php5-cgi/"
Action php5-script /__php5-cgi/php5-cgi
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

With this above, p. e., putting online a domain named `www.test-a.com` needs:

- an `adduser test-a.com` (forcing badname)
- `mkdir -p /var/www/www.test-a.com/public_html` and putting data
- files a `chmod` and a `chown`
  and **everything works fine**...

Without suEXEC I made some simple PHP tests, it works fine as uid/gid `www-data`. But now I need to enable suEXEC for isolate domains...

**The question is:** how can I tell to **suEXEC** to get automatically the right uid/gid?

I'm using the default suEXEC configuration:

```
root@web-test:/var/www# /usr/lib/apache2/suexec -V
 -D AP_DOC_ROOT="/var/www"
 -D AP_GID_MIN=100
 -D AP_HTTPD_USER="www-data"
 -D AP_LOG_EXEC="/var/log/apache2/suexec.log"
 -D AP_SAFE_PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
 -D AP_UID_MIN=100
 -D AP_USERDIR_SUFFIX="public_html"
```

But it crashes:

```
root@web-test:/var/www# tail /var/log/apache2/suexec.log 
[2012-05-05 18:31:48]: cannot run as forbidden uid (33/php5-cgi)
[2012-05-05 18:34:24]: uid: (33/www-data) gid: (33/www-data) cmd: php5-cgi
```

**Note:** I previously used `apache2-mpm-itk` but it's quite unstable after 400-500 VirtualHost definitions, especially it crashes on `apache2ctl restart|graceful"`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use mpm-itk

```
Package: apache2-mpm-itk
Description: multiuser MPM for Apache 2.2
 The ITK Multi-Processing Module (MPM) works in about the same way as the classical "prefork" module (that is, without threads),
 except that it allows you to constrain each individual vhost to a particular system user. This allows you to run several different
 web sites on a single server without worrying that they will be able to read each others' files. This is a third-party MPM that is
 not included in the normal Apache httpd.

 Please note that this MPM is somewhat less tested than the MPMs that come with Apache itself.
```

With additional [patch](http://www.pvv.ntnu.no/~knuta/mpm-itk/) you can assign uid/gid dynamically. I'm using such solution about 2 years without any problem.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.net
    ServerAlias *.example.net
    UseCanonicalName Off

    VirtualDocumentRoot /vhosts/example.net/%1
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    AssignUserFromPath "^/vhosts/example.net/([^/]+)" mvh_$1 mvh_$1

    <Directory /vhosts/example.net>
        Options -Indexes +Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [SuexecUserGroup](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_suexec.html#suexecusergroup) directive doesn't seem to support variables, so there's no easy way to do what you want. [This mailing list post](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/283583#283583) also says that it isn't possible, and that [CGIwrap](http://cgiwrap.unixtools.org/) should be used instead. The only other approach I can think of is to abuse suEXEC's [mod_userdir integration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html#usage) and somehow rewrite the requests to a user directory, but this is unlikely to work well.

Comment: Thanks mgorven. I considered `CGIwrap` too, but it's a bit complex and outdated. Finally I decided to create my own version of `suexec`, patching it from Debian sources. I'm still testing it but I'd like to publish it.
There is also a similar commercial version of Suexec from 1H Ltd, but this isn't open source and I think that's a GPL infringement. However look here: http://docs.1h.com/Suexec.